# How to create File with the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, file

How to create File with the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY  in C#? (So to store Data in Ram but be able to use it as normal file)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe you'll have to use P/Invoke to call the native `CreateFile` then use the [FileStream(SafeFileHandle, FileAccess)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6fz1x84%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) constructor on `FileStream`. [MSDN has a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.safehandles.safefilehandle.aspx) for how to use SafeFileHandle and CreateFile together.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my (C++ to C#) error within answering the question! :)

Answer (score 4):

Memory mapped files are an alternative, and are built into C# 4.0:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Using P/Invoke is too complex. Here is a simple way to create such temporary file:

```
var file = File.Create(path);
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Temporary);
```