# Flagging a file as temporary

Tags: c#, windows

Is there a way, in C# on Windows, to write a file and flag it as temporary so that the operating system won't bother physically writing it to disk? The file in question is small, and will be read by another program in the very near future, and deleted and rewritten very soon after that, so that keeping it purely in RAM would make sense.

I'm currently writing the file with `File.WriteAllText` but could use a different API if necessary.

Comment: Please, have look at `MemoryMappedFile` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: *"keeping it purely in RAM would make sense"* - Why? Have you profiled your application and determined, that this is a bottleneck?

Comment: @IInspectable It's actually not so much about speed as it is about noise - the human ear suffices to determine that the hard disk thrashing and the cooling fan spinning up, are the 'bottlenecks' for that. (You need not remind me that everyone *should* be on SSD by now.)

Comment: If you specify `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY` when creating the file, that serves as a strong hint to the file system not to bother writing it to disk.  I don't know the best way to do that in C# though.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: [that's covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940741). If only `FileOptions` had a `Temporary = 256` member, you could do this without P/Invoking to `CreateFile`, but in their wisdom the designers chose not to make this option available. (If you try to fudge it in, the `FileStream` constructor will complain.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple and could be done without any P/Invoke:

```
var file = File.Create(path);
File.SetAttributes(path, File.GetAttributes(path) | FileAttributes.Temporary);
```

The *FileAttributes.Temporary* enum value is the same as FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY constant (0x100):

> Specifying the FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY attribute causes file systems
>   to avoid writing data back to mass storage if sufficient cache memory
>   is available, because an application deletes a temporary file after a
>   handle is closed. In that case, the system can entirely avoid writing
>   the data. Although it does not directly control data caching in the
>   same way as the previously mentioned flags, the
>   FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY attribute does tell the system to hold as
>   much as possible in the system cache without writing and therefore may
>   be of concern for certain applications.

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449426%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)